# JavaScript Prototype Assignment

Tags: javascript

**What is the recommended approach/pattern for assigning an object's prototype?** Assigning a reference to an already instantiated instance of 'super' `function` or initializing a new instance of 'super' for every 'sub' `function`? If, multiple approaches are commonplace; what are the pros/cons of each?

```
function SuperFoo(){ };
function Foo() {};
function Fooy() {};
function Fooimus() {};
function Foolacious() {};


/* Option 1: */ 
var proto = new SuperFoo();
Foo.prototype = proto;
Fooy.prototype = proto;
Fooimus.prototype = proto;
Foolacious.prototype = proto;


/* Option 2: */ 
Foo.prototype = new SuperFoo();
Fooy.prototype = new SuperFoo();
Fooimus.prototype = new SuperFoo();
Foolacious.prototype = new SuperFoo();
```

Comment: Crockford's write-up on this topic should be helpful to you: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. In this state, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple approaches are commonplace. But generally, what people actually want to do isn't actually covered by any of the solutions you list.

**What you generally want from a subclass is a constructor whose `prototype` property is an object, which itself inherits from the `prototype` property of the superclass constructor.** It's also a good idea to make sure that the prototype constructors match up properly: the prototype should have a `constructor` property that points back to its own class constructor. The result can look like this:

```
function SuperFoo() {};  // assuming that some prototype functions are already defined.

function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype = Object.create(SuperFoo.prototype);
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;
```

My usual solution nowadays is to wrap this rigamarole up into a function, like so:

```
Object.subclass = function (sub, sup) {
    sub.prototype = Object.create(sup.prototype);
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
};

function SuperFoo() {};  // assuming that some prototype functions are already defined.

function Foo() {};
Object.subclass(Foo, SuperFoo);

function Fooy() {};
Object.subclass(Fooy, SuperFoo);

function Fooimus() {};
Object.subclass(Fooimus, SuperFoo);    

function Foolacious() {};
Object.subclass(Fooalicious, SuperFoo);
```